# Double click to cancel the date selection is not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Click mouse to select a date range for zooming. Double click to cancel the date selection is not working in ie 10 but working fine in less browsers:

```
function mouseClickHandler(which) {

clickx = event.offsetX;

clicky = event.offsetY;

  switch (which) {
    case "click":
        // If we've just had a doubleclick then ignore it

        if (hadDoubleClick()) return false;

        // Otherwise set timer to act.  It may be preempted by a doubleclick.
        savEvent = which;

        d = new Date();

        savEvtTime = d.getTime();

        savTO = setTimeout("doClick(savEvent)", dcTime);

        break;

    case "dblclick":

        doDoubleClick(which);

        break;

    default:
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better to use different handlers for ondblclick and onclick